# $Event not being capture by Emitting Event in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Sorry but I am new to Angular (V12) so forgive me if I am not clear with my problem. But I am essentially having an issue with the $Event not capturing my custom object data that is being emitted from another component. It is giving me with the following error when I setup the function in the parent component: error is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomObj'.
Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'prop1, prop2. When I do a console.log before I trigger the emit, I can see that my properties have successfully stored and passed on. But I am having issue displaying it.

Child Component emitting:

```
   onUpdate(myObject: objectInformation)
{
   this.edit.emit(myObject);
   console.log(this.myObject);
  }
```

Parent component:

HTML

```
<app-edit-task (edit) = "onEdit($event)"></app-edit-task>
```

TS

```
onEdit(myObject: objectInformation){
    this.currentObject= myObject;
    console.log(this.currentObject);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share the @Output, so check if the event emitter is emitting the correct type:

```
@Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<objectInformation>();
```

Also, if `objectInformation` is an object consider capitalized to `ObjectInformation`.

Now about the problem:

```
  onUpdate(myObject: objectInformation){
     this.edit.emit(myObject);
     console.log(this.myObject);
  }
```

The reason the console is working is because you are using `this.myObject` instead of `myObject`.

A little more explanation about `this`: when you are using `this` you are taking the variable `myObject` from your global scope instead of taking `myObject` from your local scope.

So, if you don't need the parameter `myObject: objectInformation`, remove it and emit your variable `myObject` from your global scope, like this:

```
 onUpdate(){
   this.edit.emit(this.myObject);
 }
```

Comment: My apologies, I did forget to include the Output. I have written it similar to what you have written above: 

@Output() edit : EventEmitter<objectInformation> = new EventEmitter();

I have removed the "this" keyboard from the console and it is works as expected both ways. I need to include the parameter myObject of type objectInformation as I get the information from the DOM:

 <app-button color="#0066cc" text="Edit Movie" (click)="onUpdate(object)"></app-button>